# Multiply 2 matrix' from text files, and output to 3rd textfile C

Tags: c, arrays

ive been on this for ages, and its not clicking for me. Im quite new to programming, so theres most likely a lot of mistakes, but hope you get the idea of what i want to do.

I have a 3 textfiles, `matrixa, matrixb, matrixc`.

I need to take a matrix from `matrixa`, (user can specify the dimensions if needed), and multiply it with a dimension in `matrixb`, and then output the result to `matrixc`, using dynamically allocated arrays.

Would really really appreciate any help

The code I currently have: nb, the code for multiplying the arrays are not included (havent done it yet)

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int i, size1, size2, n;
    int rows_matrix1, columns_matrix1, rows_matrix2, columns_matrix2;
    FILE *matrix1;
    FILE *matrix2;
    int *ptrm1, *ptrm2;

    matrix1 = fopen ("matrixa.txt", "r");
    matrix2 = fopen ("matrixb.txt", "r");

    printf ("Enter rows and columns of first matrix: \n");
    scanf ("%d %d", &rows_matrix1, &columns_matrix1);
    size1 = rows_matrix1 * columns_matrix1;
    ptrm1 = (int *) malloc (size1 * sizeof (int));

    printf ("Enter rows and columns of second matrix: \n");
    scanf ("%d %d", &rows_matrix2, &columns_matrix2);
    size2 = rows_matrix2 + columns_matrix2;
    ptrm2 = (int *) malloc (size2 * sizeof (int));

    int **my2dArray = malloc (sizeof (int *) * rows_matrix1);
    for (int n = 0; n < rows_matrix1; n++) {
        my2dArray[n] = malloc (sizeof (int) * rows_matrix1);
    }

    int **my2dArray2 = malloc (sizeof (int *) * rows_matrix2);
    for (int n = 0; n < rows_matrix2; n++) {
        my2dArray2[n] = malloc (sizeof (int) * rows_matrix2);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
        fscanf (matrix1, "%d", &ptrm1[i]);
        fscanf (matrix2, "%d", &ptrm2[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < rows_matrix1; i++) {        /*row 1 into array */
        my2dArray[i][1] = ptrm1[i];
    }

    for (i = 0; i < columns_matrix1; i++) {
        my2dArray[i][2] = ptrm1[i + rows_matrix1];
    }

    printf ("first matrix: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < columns_matrix1; i++) {
        printf ("%d ", my2dArray[i][1]);
    }
    printf ("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < columns_matrix1; i++) {
        printf ("%d ", my2dArray[i][2]);
    }

    /* MATRIX 2 */
    for (i = 0; i < rows_matrix2; i++) {        /*row 1 into array */
        my2dArray[i][1] = ptrm2[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < columns_matrix2; i++) {
        my2dArray[i][2] = ptrm2[i + rows_matrix2];
    }

    printf ("\n2nd matrix:: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < columns_matrix2; i++) {
        printf ("%d ", my2dArray[i][1]);
    }

    printf ("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < columns_matrix2; i++) {
        printf ("%d ", my2dArray[i][2]);
    }
    /*MATRIX 2 DONE*/
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the contents of files **_matrixa.txt_** and **_matrixb.txt_**

Comment: `size2 = rows_matrix2 + columns_matrix2;` Do you really want `'+'`??

Comment: It's a little odd to use `size1 = rows_matrix1 * columns_matrix1;` and then `size2 = rows_matrix2 + columns_matrix2;` — the `+` should surely be a `*`, shouldn't it?  You should be error checking your input operations, and your memory allocations.

Comment: Fixed, cheers, but it still doesnt help me much

Comment: Matrixa.txt and matrixb.txt can be filled with numbers anywich way i want

Comment: _Matrixa.txt and matrixb.txt can be filled with numbers anywich way i want_ So please [edit] your question and add a sample _matrixa.txt_ and _matrixb.txt_